# Android App Crashes at launch/ Import Error: No module named requests

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have Requests installed on Windows but I run the command `pip install requests` anyway.
I can get data from a server using Requests so I don't know why I get this error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnsMu.jpg) which happens when I launch an App I've made.
I'm not certain but I think this might be the cause to the crash which later triggers:

"Failed Looking up window"

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested  window android.os.BinderProxy@e668ad1 does not exist`

How can I fix this and stop my App from instantly crashing?

```
import requests
import json
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import time
from operator import itemgetter
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App

class placeHolder():

    def getSession():
        #Access Server
        auth = requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth('<secret>', '<secret>')
        r = requests.get('<secret>', auth=auth)
        user_info = r.json()
        r = requests.get('<secret>'.format(user_info['tanks'][0]), auth=auth)
        #print(json.loads(r.text))

        #Get the data we want
        data = []
        for i in range(len(json.loads(r.text))-5, len(json.loads(r.text))):
            important = json.loads(r.text)[i]["recorded_time"] + " " + json.loads(r.text)[i]["top_temperature"] + " " + \
                        json.loads(r.text)[i]["bottom_temperature"] + " " + json.loads(r.text)[i]["charge"]
            Data = important.split()
            data += [Data]
        return data


    def convertTime(data):
        #Need to order data so convert to unix
        for i in data:
            t = i[0] + " " + i[1]
            new_t = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(t, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())
            del i[0] #delete date
            del i[0] #now time is in 0th position, delete time
            i += [new_t]
        return data


    def orderTime(data):
        #Matplotlib needs the data to be ordered or it won't plot properly
        orderedData = sorted(data, key=itemgetter(3))
        return orderedData


    def plotData(dataToPlot):
        x = []
        yTop = []
        yBottom = []
        charge = []

        #Populate lists with data
        for i in dataToPlot:
            dateToStr = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(i[3])).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            date = datetime.datetime.strptime(dateToStr, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            yTop += [i[0]] #top temp
            yBottom += [i[1]] #bottom temp
            charge += [i[2]]
            x += [date]

        #Plot Data
        ax = plt.gca()
        ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
        plt.title("Tank Data")
        plt.plot_date(x, yTop, "r-", label="Top Temp") # labels not working
        plt.plot_date(x, yBottom, "b-", label="Bottom Temp")
        plt.plot_date(x, charge, "y-",  label="Charge")
        plt.xlabel("Time")
        plt.ylabel("Temperature")
        plt.xticks(rotation=45)
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.12, bottom=0.20, right=0.90, top=0.88)
        plt.legend(loc="best", prop={'size':9})
        plt.grid(True, linestyle="-", linewidth=0.5)

        #plt.show() Without this it works in Kivy

    def stuff():
        #Cleaner to do this here instead of within the build function below
        sessionData = placeHolder.getSession()
        selectedData = placeHolder.convertTime(sessionData)
        toPlot = placeHolder.orderTime(selectedData)
        placeHolder.plotData(toPlot)
        box = BoxLayout()
        box.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))
        return box
```

class Tank_GraphApp(App):

```
def build(self):
    box = placeHolder.stuff()
    return box

if __name__== "__main__":
    Tank_GraphApp().run()
```

Comment: add your class code

Comment: You've installed something on a Windows machine and running an App on an Android device/emulator?

Comment: I have posted the whole code if that is what you meant @OussemaAroua

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE I'm using a virtual box to put this on my phone and then I just run the pp if that is what you meant

Comment: what you cant to do exactly ?

Comment: Everything works fine on my laptop however after I download the app onto my phone and tap on it to open it, It opens for about 1 second or less with the Kivy loading screen and then it instantly crashes instead of getting the data and plotting it and staying open @OussemaAroua

Comment: maybe you are asking for something that your device doesn't support, i have no idea about kivy

Comment: Have you included "requests" in your spec file requirements?

Comment: @GeorgeBou no and I don't know where to put it

Comment: @Xzielon Have you built the Android App with Buildozer? If so you should follow the instructions about the spec file. Every module you use must be written in the spec file. It even includes the "requests" module in the official example.